# Dynamic permutation cycle data

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, permutations, online-algorithms

Let $\pi \in S_n$ be a permutation of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. Does there exist a simple data structure that admits the following operations in polylogarithmic time?

- **sameCycle**($\pi,x,y$): determines whether $x$ and $y$ belong to the same permutation cycle;
- **transpose**($\pi,x,y$): replaces $\pi$ by the composition $(xy)\pi$ of the transposition $(xy)$ with $\pi$.

This can be viewed as a special case of the [fully-dynamic graph connectivity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Fully_dynamic_connectivity) in which the connected components are always cycles. [Therefore it admits such a data structure](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2552), but one may hope that the cycle structure makes the problem easier and/or faster.

Comment: Sounds something that should be doable with link/cut trees with $O(\log n)$ complexity because cycles are just one edge away from trees.